# C# открытие порта

Tags: c#

Всем привет, пытаюсь на C# прослушать порт, но при открытии пишет , что такого порта нет, хотя я создал правило в брандмауере и в cmd его нет, я в сети роутера, сделал там себе статический ip и сделал на нем проброс к себе на пк, на порт,

```
        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort(); //Create a new SerialPort object.
        serialPort.PortName = "COM11003";
        serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;

        serialPort.Open();
```

через 2ip сайт, показывает, что порт на роутере открыт

Answer (score 1):

SerialPort - это последовательный порт (RS232 и подобные), в современных условиях обычно USB-переходник, это не сетевой порт.

Вероятно, вам нужен TcpListener